# c++: How to correct transfer array of char strings into function?

Tags: c++, string, function, struct, char

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct st
{
  string name[3];
  st(char X[][]) { for(int i=0; i<3; i++) name[i] = X[i];} 
} Y( {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"} );
```

But Y( {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"} ) didn't work. And i don't know right answer. Help please.

This works fine.

```
struct st
    {
      string name;
      st(char X[]) { name[i] = X;} 
    } Y("Text1");
```

Comment: Nonsense. Read some introductory C++ **book** first. Dont ask question just for sake of asking it. Learn the basics first, do some exercises, then ask question if you've face any problem solving the exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using C++11

```
struct st
{
    array<string, 3> name;
    st(const array<string, 3>& name)
        : name(name)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    st s({ "Text1", "Text2", "Text3" });
    cout << s.name[0] << endl;
}
```

Live example
http://ideone.com/cxMNnX

Answer (score 1):

If to comment the wrong member function declaration and substitute parentheses for braces then the code will be compiled. :)

```
    struct st
    {
        std::string name[3];
//          std(char X[][]) { for(int i=0; i<3; i++) name[i] = X[i];} 
    } Y { {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3"} };
```

As for the member function (it seems you wanted to define a constructor) then it could be defined like

```
st( const char *s[3] ) 
{
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) name[i] = s[i]; 
}
```

Or you could define the structure like

```
struct st
{
    std::string name[3];
    st( std::initializer_list<const char *> l ) 
    {
        size_t n = std::min<size_t>( 3, l.size() );
        std::copy_n( l.begin(), n, name ); 
    }   
} Y ( {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3" } );
```

Comment: It was just example. Constructor has many parameters, how then?